# Некорректное описание причины закрытия темы

Tags: предложение, причины-закрытия

Есть причина закрытия темы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По сути, вопрос ещё не закрыт, а только рекомендуется к закрытию. Я понимаю, что данное описание используется для корректного отображения причины уже после закрытия вопроса.
Предлагаю исправить на что-то вроде:

> На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято
>   задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на
>   русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Помимо всего, когда вопрос будет закрыт, ТС (если он англоговорящий) не поймёт причину закрытия. В таком случае можно перевести после русского описания причины:

> На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято
>   задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на
>   русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском. / On the Stack Overflow in Russian questions being asked only in Russian. Please, translate your question in Russian or use Stack Overflow in English.

Comment: Предлагаю запостить нижний вариант в виде ответа, чтобы другие могли предлагать и свои варианты.

Comment: @D-side добавил

Comment: как уже неоднократно обсуждалось, люди, которые создают вопросы на английском на этом сайте, прекрасно русский понимают (попробуйте нажать на кнопку и задать вопрос [на японском сайте](http://jp.stackoverflow.com), не зная японского языка).

Comment: @D-side надо либо описание метки [meta-tag:предложение] править, либо не предлагать выносить в ответы. Уже не первый раз об этом вспоминаю.

Comment: @alexolut я всего лишь **высказываю *своё* предложение** :)

Comment: @D-side я не то чтобы с наездом :) Просто какая-то неоднозначность получается с этим тегом. Хотя смотрю, в подробном описании есть и про варианты в ответах. Но вроде как смысл именно в альтернативных авторскому (в вопросе) вариантах.

Comment: @alexolut никакой неоднозначности. Здесь указание на то, что некоторый момент сайта можно улучшить, и предлагается его улучшить. Как именно -- дело ответов. Важно, что рассматриваемый "момент" не является дефектом.

Comment: @D-side ответы имеют смысл только для : 
  `-  Дополнительную аргументацию в поддержку предложения;
  -  Вариант реализации предлагаемого изменения функциональности;
 -  Аргументацию против реализации предложения.` Т.е. авторский вариант нет смысла выносить из тела вопроса, кмк.

Comment: @alexolut `- Вариант реализации предлагаемого изменения функциональности;` в чистом виде.

Comment: @D-side в чистом виде его достаточно в самом вопросе, иначе не понятно что вообще значит голосование за **вопрос**.

Comment: @alexolut признание или непризнание проблемы и необходимости её решать.

Comment: @D-side это не согласуется с описанием `Для таких вопросов голоса «за» и «против» обозначают согласие или несогласие с предложением, а не качество или полезность вопроса.`

Comment: @alexolut отлично согласуется. Эту проблему нужно или не нужно решать, "согласен с её существованием или нет".

Comment: @D-side ой, всё!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант правки причины закрытия вопроса с переводом:

> На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на
>   русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или
>   воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском. / On the Stack Overflow
>   in Russian questions being asked only in Russian. Please, translate
>   your question in Russian or use Stack Overflow in English.

Comment: гугл транслейтом переводили :)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko есть такое :)

Answer (score 0):

> На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском./
>   On Stack Overflow in Russian, as the name implies questions can be only asked in Russian, so please translate your question (into Russian) or use [Stack Overflow in English](https://stackoverflow.com/) .